# Combine overlapping categorical variables

Tags: stata

I am trying to "combine" two categorical variables in Stata (say `var1` and `var2`) into a new (also categorical) variable (say `res`).

The example below illustrates what I am trying to achieve:

```
var1    var2    res
1       1       A
1       2       A
2       1       A
3       3       B
4       2       A
5       4       D
```

What this example does is to combine all categories of `var1` and `var2` that "overlap".

Here, the pair `var1 == 1` and `var2 == 1` initially form a group (`res== A`). All other pairs containing `var1 == 1` or `var2 == 1` should belong to the same group (hence `res== A` in rows 2 and 3). Because in row 2 we have `var2==2`, any pair with containing `var2==2` should belong to the same group. That's why in row 4 `res== A`.

Another way to look at this problem is using the following matrix:

```
     |  1   2   3   4
-----------------------        
   1 |  1   1       
   2 |  1           
   3 |          1   
   4 |      1       
   5 |              1
```

Because the element `[1,1]` is not empty (or zero), all elements in row `1` and column `1` must belong to the same group. Because `[1,2]` is not empty, the same is true for row `1`, column `2`. And so on and so forth. It does not matter which row/column you decide to start from.

`egen group` alone doesn't cut it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want to further group `var1` if the values of `var2` are the same. If that's the case, then you can use a program I wrote called `group_id` that's available from SSC. To install it, type in Stata's Command window:

```
ssc install group_id
```

Here's an example of how you would use it:

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input float(var1 var2) str1 res
1 1 "A"
1 2 "A"
2 1 "A"
3 3 "B"
4 2 "A"
5 4 "D"
end

gen long wanted = var1
group_id wanted, matchby(var2)

list, sep(0)
```

and the results:

```
. list, sep(0)

     +----------------------------+
     | var1   var2   res   wanted |
     |----------------------------|
  1. |    1      1     A        1 |
  2. |    1      2     A        1 |
  3. |    2      1     A        1 |
  4. |    3      3     B        3 |
  5. |    4      2     A        1 |
  6. |    5      4     D        5 |
     +----------------------------+
```

Comment: Yes, this appears to be the case and the best/simplest way to go about it.